# Odeint error for nonlineal differential equations

Tags: python, ode, scipy, numpy, differential-equations

I receive the following error when I run the code.

> ODEintWarning: Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun
> type). Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information. warnings.warn(warning_msg,
> ODEintWarning)

I got this from messing around with an example received from my professor and can't seem to understand what is happening.

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def f(y, t):
    return y ** 2
    
t = np.linspace(0, 5, 100) 
x0 =  3             
x = odeint(f, x0, t)
```

Answer (score 1):

The exact solution is $$x(t)=\frac{3}{1-3t}.$$ This means that the domain of the solution is $(-\infty,\frac13)$. `odeint` with the integration interval $[0,5]$ stalls at this singularity, as it can, correctly, not move beyond this point.